# Which is a good JavaScript framework to learn for gaming purposes?

Tags: javascript-framework, webgl, maya

The Khronos Group gives an extensive [list](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/User_Contributions#Frameworks) of WebGL frameworks and I'm stuck on choosing a well documented one focusing on 3D game play rather then searching for examples that explain specific techniques.  Which would be best for someone with a  background in Engineering Design? I have a Maya Scene that I want to convert into multiple high-res objects, then render and manipulate with the help of a WebGL framework.  Something that has the ability to import OBJs with materials, texture and shaders intact would be ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Questions like this are difficult to answer, because we know almost nothing about your skill level, the type of game you want to create, any external requirements you may have (ie: what browsers should it be compatible with? What types of hardware) and other factors that all play a vital role in determining what libraries you choose to use in any given project.

After all, if there was a single "perfect" framework for any given situation there would be no need for the list you linked! Every framework has it's pros and cons, and in many cases it's up to you to experiment with them and see what works for you.

If you're completely unsure of where to start and this is one of your first forays into 3D programming I would suggest looking at [ThreeJS](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) first. I recommend it purely because I know of no other framework that sees such widespread use, which means that there's a lot of community resources (blogs, source code, demos) available and a lot of people that can help you when you get stuck. (And you **will** get stuck!) I will tell you right now that it's not the fastest of the frameworks in that list, but to be blunt performance is the least of your worries at this stage. You need to figure out gameplay, your resource toolchain, and a few other basics before speed matters. (Rendering triangles blazingly fast doesn't matter if you can't get your play model to show up.)

Otherwise you need to sit down for yourself and decide exactly what kind of game you are making and what you the framework to provide for you, then go down the list, read a little about each one, and decide which one aligns most closely with your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you start off in Maya then www.inka3d.com should be the right thing for you. You can do as much as possible in maya, for example animations, shaders and even mel scripts, and then export it to javascript. then you can control the maya attributes of your scene from javascript.